# Python argparse: "unrecognized arguments"

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to use my program with command line option. Here is my code:

```
import argparse

def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-u","--upgrade", help="fully automatized upgrade")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.upgrade:
        print "Starting with upgrade procedure"
main()
```

When I try to run my program from terminal (`python script.py -u`), I expect to get the message `Starting with upgrade procedure`, but instead I get the error message `unrecognized arguments -u`.

Comment: I am not seeing any error message and I am getting your expecpted output; I think it could be because of space, tab in your program Please verify that                                                                              [viswesn.viswesn-PC] ➤ python script.py -u 10
Starting with upgrade procedure                                                     [viswesn.viswesn-PC] ➤ python script.py -u
usage: script.py [-h] [-u UPGRADE]
script.py: error: argument -u/--upgrade: expected one argument

Comment: The only issue here, is that `-u` will expect a value or some sort. try doing `python myscript.py -u True`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error you are getting is because `-u` is expecting a some value after it. If you use `python script.py -h` you will find it in usage statement saying `[-u UPGRADE]`.

If you want to use it as boolean or flag (true if `-u` is used), add an additional parameter `action`:

```
parser.add_argument("-u","--upgrade", help="fully automatized upgrade", action="store_true")
```

`action` - The basic type of action to be taken when this argument is encountered at the command line

With `action="store_true"`, if the option `-u` is specified, the value True is assigned to `args.upgrade`. Not specifying it implies False.

Source: [Python argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method)

Answer (score 3):

Currently, your argument requires a value to be passed in for it as well.

If you want `-u` as an option instead, Use the [`action='store_true'`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action) for arguments that do not need a value.

Example -

```
parser.add_argument("-u","--upgrade", help="fully automatized upgrade", action='store_true')
```

Answer (score 3):

For Boolean arguments use action="store_true":

```
parser.add_argument("-u","--upgrade", help="fully automatized upgrade", action="store_true")
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#introducing-optional-arguments